# How to join on same table twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables:
1. transaction table with transaction id and start and end points
2. stand table with point names

I need a single entry against each transaction in this format:
transaction id, start point, name of start point, end point, name of end point

```
select t.id, t.start_point, s.name, t.end_point, s1.name
from transaction t 
left join stand s on s.stand_id = t.start_point and s.state = 2
left join stand s1 on s.stand_id = t.end_point and s1.state = 2
where t.state = 2 and date(t.created_at) = curdate()-1
and t.start_point is not null and t.end_point is not null
```

My resut count should be 3660, but what i get is 8462. I get 3660 without the s1 left join. How can I change this query?

Comment: `left join stand s1 on s.stand_id = t.end_point` should probably be `left join stand s1 on s1.stand_id = t.end_point`

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the correction, and thanks for not answering a typo question :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen pity about all the others...

Comment: I mean, they could at least take 60-90 seconds and properly format the answer, rather than just cutting and pasting, changing a few characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an wrong `s` - instead of `s1` at `left join stand s1 on s1.stand_id = t.end_point and s1.state = 2` 
try

```
select t.id, t.start_point, s.name, t.end_point, s1.name
from transaction t 
left join stand s on s.stand_id = t.start_point and s.state = 2
left join stand s1 on s1.stand_id = t.end_point and s1.state = 2
where t.state = 2 and date(t.created_at) = curdate()-1
and t.start_point is not null and t.end_point is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `s1.stand_id = t.end_point` for 2nd join condition

```
select t.id, t.start_point, s.name, t.end_point, s1.name
from transaction t 
left join stand s on s.stand_id = t.start_point and s.state = 2
left join stand s1 on s1.stand_id = t.end_point and s1.state = 2
where t.state = 2 and date(t.created_at) = curdate()-1
and t.start_point is not null and t.end_point is not null
```